# How to solve "cabal: Could not resolve dependencies" when building cardano-cli cardano-node

Tags: stake-pool, cardano-node, cabal, staking

I'm a newbie to Cardano. I'm trying to set up a stake pool as this link explained.

https://www.coincashew.com/coins/overview-ada/guide-how-to-build-a-haskell-stakepool-node

I stuck with `cabal build cardano-cli cardano-node` step with the following error.

```
Warning: Requested index-state 2021-04-30T00:00:00Z is newer than
'hackage.haskell.org'! Falling back to older state (2021-04-29T23:07:55Z).
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: Win32-network-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] trying: base-4.14.1.0/installed-4.14.1.0 (dependency of Win32-network)
[__2] trying: lobemo-scribe-systemd-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__3] next goal: libsystemd-journal (dependency of lobemo-scribe-systemd)
[__3] rejecting: libsystemd-journal-1.4.5 (conflict: pkg-config package
libsystemd>=209, not found in the pkg-config database)
[__3] rejecting: libsystemd-journal-1.4.4 (conflict:
base==4.14.1.0/installed-4.14.1.0, libsystemd-journal => base>=4.6 && <4.13)
[__3] skipping: libsystemd-journal-1.4.3, libsystemd-journal-1.4.2,
libsystemd-journal-1.4.1, libsystemd-journal-1.4.0, libsystemd-journal-1.3.4,
libsystemd-journal-1.3.3, libsystemd-journal-1.3.1, libsystemd-journal-1.3.0,
libsystemd-journal-1.2.0, libsystemd-journal-1.1.0, libsystemd-journal-1.0.0
(has the same characteristics that caused the previous version to fail:
excludes 'base' version 4.14.1.0)
[__3] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, libsystemd-journal,
lobemo-scribe-systemd)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, libsystemd-journal,
lobemo-scribe-systemd, Win32-network
Try running with --minimize-conflict-set to improve the error message.
```

Anyone can enlighten me to solve this, please?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the command in nix-shell?

If not, I'd suggest you clone the Plutus project, run `nix-shell` from within the Plutus repository.

Afterwards, try building the libs again

Comment: Oh, I also newbie for nix-shell. I gonna try, thank you.

Comment: @Aoaddeola I do not think he's trying to set up the Plutus environment.

Comment: @Kelli Ahh, yes, I just trying to set up a stake pool.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue is with Cabal and its dependencies versions, specifically the packages (base, libsystemd-journal,lobemo-scribe-systemd and Win32-network).

I think this link will help:

https://forum.cardano.org/t/error-message-trying-the-comand-cabal-build-installing-my-cardano-node/41605/8

Other similar issues:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68558825/could-not-resolve-dependencies-while-installing-libraries-with-cabal

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67154347/how-can-i-fix-haskell-version-conflicts-with-dependencies